# Use forms to get data from users in a gmail using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

How to make my website receive data from users and send it to me as a gmail??

So I want to receive the data that users put in as a gmail while having my form verification still work properly, and I am still a newbie in this coding world so I still didn't learn about php or python or jQuery so is there any way to make javascript send me the data as a gmail and if there is no other way can someone show me the php code that would make it work thank you!

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const tely = document.getElementById('tely');

form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();
    
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit() ;
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
     }

});

function isFormValid(){
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-control');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container)=>{
        if(container.classList.contains('error')){
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPhone = tely => {
    const phone = /^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/;
    return phone.test(tely);
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const telyValue = tely.value.trim();

    if(firstnameValue === '') {
        setError(firstname, 'First Name is required');
    } else {
        setSuccess(firstname);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, 'Email is required');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, 'Provide a valid Email address');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if(lastnameValue === '') {
        setError(lastname, 'Last Name is required');
    }else {
        setSuccess(lastname);
    }

    if(telyValue === '') {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number is required');
    } else if (!isValidPhone(telyValue)) {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number must be of 10 characters');
    } else {
        setSuccess(tely);
    }

};
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Rebrand-header;
    src: url(./fonts/Rebrand\ Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
    src: url(./fonts/Henderson\ Sans.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-bold;
    src: url(./fonts/HendersonSans\ Bold.otf);
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    background-color: #f1eff4;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 41%;
}

.logo{
  background-image: url("./images/header\ 2.png");  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  
}

.header h1{
    font-family: Rebrand-header;
    color: #0c0c4c;
    font-size: 300%;
}

.heading{
    margin-left:10px;
    color: #0c0c4c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
}

#all{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#firstname{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#lastname{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#email{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#tely{
    margin-top: 3px;
}



#form{
    width:300px;
    margin:5vh auto 0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
}


#form button{
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:50%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #1c1ce5;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:80px ;
}

#form button:hover{
    color: #1c1ce5;
    background:white ;
}

.input-control{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.input-control input{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:9px;
    width:100%;
}

.input-control input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

.input-control.success input{
    border-color: #09c372;
}

.input-control.error input{
    border-color: #ff3860;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-control.error{
    color: #ff3860;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:9px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    .header{
        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-left: 19%;
        display: flex;
    }

    .logo{
        background-image: url("./images/header\ 2.png");  
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top: 6%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        
      }

  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h1>carma</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form id="form" action="./page3.html" method="GET"><!--onsubmit="sendData(); reset(); return false;"-->
        <div class="input-control" id="all">
            <label for="firstname" class="heading">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <div class="error"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-control" id="all">
            <label for="lastname" class="heading">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
            <div class="error"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-control" id="all">
            <label for="email" class="heading">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <div class="error"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-control" id="all">
            <label for="tely" class="heading">Phone Number</label>
            <input id="tely" name="tely" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <div class="error"></div>
        </div>

        <button id="btn" class="Start-btn" type="submit" value="submit">Next</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <!--<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>

    <script>
       var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
       btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var form = document.getElementById('form').value;
        var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var tely = document.getElementById('tely').value;
        var body = 'First Name: ' +firstname + '<br/> Last Name: ' +lastname + '<br/> Email: ' + email + '<br/> Phone Number: ' +tely;

        Email.send({
        SecureToken : "79279201-061d-4b86-86d7-55819025b872",
        To : 'rimas.abutaha@gmail.com',
        From : "codingrim6@gmail.com",
        Subject : "Contact Message",
        Body : body
        }).then(
        message => alert(message)
        );

       })

    </script>-->
```

I watched videos where they used STMP but I still couldn't get a gmail with the user's data and it made the form's verification not work so baiscally my javascript stopped working so does anyone know how to fix my code plz

Answer (score -1):

You need server side code to be able to send an email.  It can be done, but then your server might be flagged as spam since it probably hasn't sent out a lot of email.

Honestly, it's complex and frustrating.  I highly recommend using a service like https://formspree.io - it's super easy and free.

Comment: Thank you very much but formspree redirects to their thank you page and I need to be redirected to another page in my project

Comment: @Rimas Not if you use a javascript form: https://formspree.io/javascript/ once it return you can do whatever action you want to. This is what I do on my websites where I use FormSpree

Comment: wouldn't I have to pay for that?

Comment: No, it's free. That's why I am recommending it. I use it on my Angular website. Here's the source code where I do that: https://github.com/FiniteLooper/chrisbarr.me/blob/main/src/app/contact/contact.component.ts#L28-L50

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me alottt

Comment: @Rimas Great, I'm glad!  Please mark this answer as accepted if this is what worked for you